# python - socket download image

Tags: python, image, sockets, download, binary

Good morning, community.

After hours of google I'm starting this thread. 
I'm trying to download a picture from www with the python socket module. 
I'm getting the source of the picture with "recv()" and writing it in binary mode to a file.
Splitting the content from header with "answer.split("image/jpeg")" does not solve the problem.

Heres my code:

```
import socket

socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)

HOST = 'ict.de'   
PORT = 80         

def makestr(s):#create paket-string from list
    rs = ""
    for x in range(0,len(s)-1):
            rs+=s[x]+"\r\n"
    rs+="\r\n"
    return rs

def sendcap(sdata):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(sdata)

    recvd=""
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data: print " Done "; break
        recvd += data
    data = recvd.split("image/jpeg")[1]
    s.close()

    return data

xy = []  
xy.append("GET /fileadmin/ict/images/Presse/Download-Button_1700x1000.jpg HTTP/1.1")
xy.append("Host: www.ict.de")
xy.append("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101      Firefox/19.0")
xy.append("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
xy.append("Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
xy.append("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate")
xy.append("DNT: 1")
xy.append("Connection: keep-alive")
data = sendcap(makestr(xy))
f = open("logo.jpg","wb")
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

data in plain text is something like this (without header,split at image/jpeg) "ÿØÿá5ExifMM*bj(1r2Ž‡i¤Ð ü€' ü€'Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows2012:03:05 13:37:44  ¤ è&(. ÿHHÿØÿíAdobe_CMÿîAdobed€ÿÛ„         ÿÀ^ "ÿÝ ÿÄ?       3!1AQa"q2‘¡±B#$RÁb34r‚ÑC%’Sðáñcs5¢²ƒ&D“TdEÂ£t6ÒUâeò³„"

looks like binary-data.

When I'm trying to open the file with windows picture show, it gets an error, that the file is corrupted.

Hope somebody is able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

splitting at `'image/jpeg'` doesn't work, because after that there are two `'\r\n'`s terminating the HTTP headers.

The headers are not guaranteed to come in any particular order, so processing a response like this may suddenly stop to work.

If anything you should look for the end of headers mark:

```
data = recvd.split("\r\n\r\n", 1)[1]
```

But of course this only works if the conent isn't sent [chunked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

There are libraries designed to do this sort of things ([requests](http://docs.python-requests.org), [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)), why don't you use them?

Comment: I worked with urllib2, but i want to learn how it works at a lower level. I Thought the \r\n\r\n marks the end of the paket. Going to try it. - edit: IT works ;) - changing "data = recvd.split("image/jpeg")"[1] to "data = recvd.split("\r\n\r\n")[1]"